# How to iterate through a QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, iteration, qstring, qlist

I'm trying to iterate through two different directories. The two directories are on the same root `/`.

```
void MainWindow::loadPlugins()
{
    pluginsDir = QDir(qApp -> applicationDirPath());

#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    if (pluginsDir.dirName().toLower() == "debug" || pluginsDir.dirName().toLower() == "release")
        pluginsDir.cdUp();
#elif defined(Q_OS_MAC)
    if (pluginsDir.dirName() == "MacOS") {
        pluginsDir.cdUp();
        pluginsDir.cdUp();
        pluginsDir.cdUp();
    }
#endif

    QStringList dirs;
    dirs << "plugins" << "core_plugs";

    QList<QObject *> loadedPlugs;

    for (int i = 0; i < dirs.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << dirs.at(i).toLocal8Bit().constData() << endl;

        pluginsDir.cd(dirs.at(i).toLocal8Bit().constData());

        foreach (QString fileName, pluginsDir.entryList(QDir::Files)) {
            QPluginLoader loader(pluginsDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName));
            QObject *plugin = loader.instance();
            qDebug() << "NAME :: " << fileName;
            if (plugin && !(loadedPlugs . contains(plugin))) {
                loadedPlugs << plugin;
                dirs . removeAt(i);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only able to go into the first directory **plugins** in the list `dirs << "plugins" << "core_plugs";`. With a re-order `dirs << "core_plugs" << "plugins";`, the results are the same, and only the first directory, **core_plugs** is parsed.

Why am I getting this behavior, and how can I make it iterate through both directories.

**UPDATE**

```
void MainWindow::loadPlugins()
{
    pluginsDir = QDir(qApp -> applicationDirPath());

#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    if (pluginsDir.dirName().toLower() == "debug" || pluginsDir.dirName().toLower() == "release")
        pluginsDir.cdUp();
#elif defined(Q_OS_MAC)
    if (pluginsDir.dirName() == "MacOS") {
        pluginsDir.cdUp();
        pluginsDir.cdUp();
        pluginsDir.cdUp();
    }
#endif

    QStringList dirs;
    dirs << "plugins" << "core_plugs";

    QList<QObject *> loadedPlugs;

    for (int i = 0; i < dirs.size(); ++i)
    {
        pluginsDir.cd(dirs.at(i).toLocal8Bit().constData());

        foreach (QString fileName, pluginsDir.entryList(QDir::Files)) {
            QPluginLoader loader(pluginsDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName));
            QObject *plugin = loader.instance();
            if (plugin && !(loadedPlugs . contains(plugin))) {
                populateRevPlugins(plugin);
                loadedPlugs << plugin;
            }
        }
        qDebug() << pluginsDir . absolutePath();
        pluginsDir.cdUp();
        qDebug() << pluginsDir . absolutePath();
    }
}
```

Following [Azeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7670262/azeem?tab=profile)'s suggestion, I updated my attempt as shown above. I tried to `cdUp();` after the `foreach` i.e:

```
foreach() {} pluginsDir.cdUp();
```

But, it doesn't get caught. It's too late there. Sooner than that and I get too few iterations. Could you please suggest how I can particularly go about it?

Thank you for the response!

Comment: Why is it so late? And, what do you mean by "it doesn't get caught"?

Comment: I'm unable to iterate into the second directory. The `pluginsDir.cdUp();` works, and the directory changes, but no iteration happens into the second directory. It seems like `cdUp` happens after the iteration is over.

Comment: Here's the stripped down version of your code: http://ideone.com/H3qY81 and it works fine! You need to check `cd` for error handling.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is how you can iterate through a [`QStringList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html) using C++11's [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```cpp
const QStringList list { "A", "B", "C" };

for ( const auto& i : list )
{
    qDebug() << i;
}
```

But, I believe that your problem is not the iteration. Your problem is that you are `cd`ing into a directory but not getting out of it i.e. `cd("..")` or `cdUp()`.

See [`QDir::cd()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#cd) and [`QDir::cdUp()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#cdUp) functions for more details.

As you said that both these directories are in the same path,
so after processing in the nested loop, you need to get back up to the root directory path to access the other directories at the same level.

You can simply check the result of the `QDir::cd()` function whether it was successful or not. It is a Boolean function. But, in your case, the error handling is missing. With proper error handling, it should be like this:

```cpp
if ( dir.cd(path) )
{
    // Do something here
}
```

You don't have to get the `dirs.at(i).toLocal8Bit().constData()` for the `cd` function. It takes a `QString`.

Here is its signature:

```cpp
bool QDir::cd( const QString& dirName );
```

---

You can also use [QDirIterator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html) for iterating a directory.

---

Here is a complete working example.

**Directory structure**:

```
C:\Test
-- A
---- a.txt
-- B
---- b.txt
```

**Code**:

```cpp
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>

int main()
{
    const QString     root { "C:/Test" };
    const QStringList dirs { "A", "B" };

    QDir rootDir { root };
    qDebug() << "Root Path:" << rootDir.absolutePath();
    qDebug() << "Root List:" << rootDir.entryList( QDir::Dirs ) << '\n';

    for ( const auto& dir : dirs )
    {
        if ( rootDir.cd(dir) )
        {
            qDebug() << "Dir Path:" << rootDir.absolutePath();
            qDebug() << "Dir List:" << rootDir.entryList( QDir::Files ) << '\n';
        }

        rootDir.cdUp();
        qDebug() << "cding...";
        qDebug() << "Dir Path:" << rootDir.absolutePath() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi @Azeem. I'm trying to `cdUp();` after the foreach ie: `foreach() {} pluginsDir.cdUp();`, but it doesn't get caught. It's too late there. Sooner than that and I get too few iterations. Could you please suggest how I can particularly go about it? Thank you for the response.

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev: Hello! Can you update your code please? BTW, you don't need that `else { continue; }` at the end of the nested loop. It's going to reiterate when the `if` condition is not true and I believe that your intention is also the same.

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev: You can simply create the fully qualified path while `cd`ing like this: `pluginsDir.cd( "/" + dir.at(i) );` That'll do it. And, you won't need that `cdUp()` after the loop. :)

Comment: Thank so much @Azeem. I couldn't have figured this without your help. I can't be thankful enough.